# Override maven-assembly-plugin output file name

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Is it possible to override the default name of the jar file created running the `assembly:single` goal? I want to add a jar with dependencies that has a non-standard name. I am using version 2.6 of the plugin.

Comment: Why not just rename the file with copy-rename-maven-plugin. It actually will give the same outcome.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the [`finalName`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#finalName) configuration attribute. Note that you probaby also want to remove the assembly id that is appended by default to the final name, with the help of the [`appendAssemblyId`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#appendAssemblyId) attribute.

Sample configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    ...
    <finalName>myFinalName</finalName>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: there is no "finalName" in the assembly plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html

Comment: to @jason : there is no "finalname" field but it works... I do not know the magic involved...

Comment: There is indeed a `finalName` parameter in the _single_ goal. It is not generated in the documentation, and it's declared as "read only" : see [source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-assembly-plugin/blob/maven-assembly-plugin-3.3.0/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/assembly/mojos/AbstractAssemblyMojo.java#L144). So it should normally not be possible to set it in the configuration, but it's a side effect (or a bug) in Maven 3. See [MNG-5001](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5001) or [MJAR-264](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-264).

Comment: As of v3.60 of the plugin, `finalName` is [no longer marked as read-only in the source](https://github.com/apache/maven-assembly-plugin/blob/bf990b1745f1ef0d84277e8d787e6e7fc5c7fc99/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/assembly/mojos/AbstractAssemblyMojo.java#L143), and it [shows up in the docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html). The documentation indicates a caveat, though, that this only affects the resource generated in the `target` directory and not installed/deployed artifacts.

Answer (score 7):

The proper way to do this (as mentioned [on Maven JIRA tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-264?focusedCommentId=16837196&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16837196)) is to set the `build.finalName` and not to use the readonly `finalName` plugin property. Here is an example how to get rid of both the "jar-with-dependencies" and the version, which is very useful for creating a stable name and eliminating potentially confusing existence of 2 JARs for use in README instructions:

```
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
...
            <configuration>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
...
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```